# android 12 deep-linking, support multiple apps, not showing App chooser

Tags: deep-linking, android-12

On Android 12, I want to show two app options on app chooser for deeplinking. I have added both app certificate details like package id and SHA into assetlinks.json , but App chooser is not showing. its redirecting directly to the app whichever we install first.